# SQL - insert que receba valores calculados de outras colunas de outras tabelas

Tags: postgresql

Quero fazer um insert onde a coluna valor_venda (da tabela vendas) seja preenchida de forma automática que será o 
valor_unitário(contido na tabela produtos) * a quantidade (esta na tabela de vendas).

Alguém sabe informar como se faz isso?

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que sua estrutura e seus dados sejam algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_vendas
(
      id SERIAL,
      id_produto INTEGER,
      valor_venda REAL,
      quantidade INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE tb_produto
(
      id INTEGER,
      nome TEXT,
      valor_unitario REAL
);

-- PRODUTOS CADASTRADOS
INSERT INTO tb_produto( id, nome, valor_unitario ) VALUES ( 1, 'CANETA', 1.50 );
INSERT INTO tb_produto( id, nome, valor_unitario ) VALUES ( 2, 'LAPIS', 0.55 );
INSERT INTO tb_produto( id, nome, valor_unitario ) VALUES ( 3, 'GRAMPEADOR', 14.50 );
INSERT INTO tb_produto( id, nome, valor_unitario ) VALUES ( 4, 'CADERNO', 4.75 );
```

Você pode "cadastrar" suas `vendas` dessa forma:

```
-- VENDEU 3 CADERNOS
INSERT INTO tb_vendas ( id_produto, quantidade, valor_venda )
(SELECT p.id, 3, p.valor_unitario * 3 FROM tb_produto AS p WHERE p.id = 4);

-- VENDEU 2 GRAMPEADORES
INSERT INTO tb_vendas ( id_produto, quantidade, valor_venda )
(SELECT p.id, 2, p.valor_unitario * 2 FROM tb_produto AS p WHERE p.id = 3);

-- VENDEU 10 LAPIS
INSERT INTO tb_vendas ( id_produto, quantidade, valor_venda )
(SELECT p.id, 10, p.valor_unitario * 10 FROM tb_produto AS p WHERE p.id = 2);

-- VENDEU 7 CANETAS
INSERT INTO tb_vendas ( id_produto, quantidade, valor_venda )
(SELECT p.id, 7, p.valor_unitario * 7 FROM tb_produto AS p WHERE p.id = 1);
```

Verificando as `vendas`:

```
SELECT
    v.id,
    p.nome,
    p.valor_unitario,
    v.quantidade,
    v.valor_venda
FROM
    tb_vendas AS v
JOIN
    tb_produto AS p ON ( p.id = v.id_produto  );
```

Saída:

```
| id |       nome | valor_unitario | quantidade | valor_venda |
|----|------------|----------------|------------|-------------|
| 24 |     CANETA |            1.5 |          7 |        10.5 |
| 23 |      LAPIS |           0.55 |         10 |         5.5 |
| 22 | GRAMPEADOR |           14.5 |          2 |          29 |
| 21 |    CADERNO |           4.75 |          3 |       14.25 |
```

Veja funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ced41/4)

Outra solução alternativa é a implementação de uma `FUNCTION` capaz de registrar uma `venda` a partir do `id` do `produto` e da `quantidade` vendida:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fc_registrar_venda( INTEGER, INTEGER )
RETURNS INTEGER AS
$$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tb_vendas ( id_produto, quantidade, valor_venda )
   (SELECT p.id, $2, p.valor_unitario * $2 FROM tb_produto AS p WHERE p.id = $1);
   RETURN currval( pg_get_serial_sequence('tb_vendas','id') );
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Registrando as `vendas` com a `FUNCTION`:

```
-- COMPROU 3 CADERNOS
SELECT fc_registrar_venda( 4, 3 );

-- COMPROU 2 GRAMPEADORES
SELECT fc_registrar_venda( 3, 2 );

-- COMPROU 10 LAPIS
SELECT fc_registrar_venda( 2, 10 );

-- COMPROU 7 CANETAS
SELECT fc_registrar_venda( 1, 7 );
```

Veja funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/23ce9/2)

Comment: +1! Talvez explicar no topo, a título de resumo, algo como "você pode inserir o resultado de um `select`, não somente dados *puros*"

Answer (score 0):

Com Sub Select:

```
INSERT INTO VENDAS (produto,quantidade,valor_venda) values 
(::produto,::quantidade,((select valor_unitario from produtos where codigo = ::produto)*::quantidade));
```

onde `::produto` é o código do produto que você vai inserir na venda,
e `::quantidade` é a quantidade que você vai inserir na venda.